# Move Moodle from remote to local WAMP server

Tags: localhost, wamp, moodle, remote-server

How to move/copy a moodle site from remote to a local WAMP server. I already installed the WAMP server on my windows machine, already downloaded via ftp the whole moodle site.
Now I'm on the installing part of moodle, and I don't know what settings should I made to connect somehow the downloaded moodle with the local one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still connecting to the same database, or are you wanting a local copy of the database? (The second is more likely)

In the first instance, you will need to look at the settings in the config.php on the original server to get the details of the remote database to connect to (if your database even allows connections remotely).

If you need a local copy of the database, then you need to use some tool to export the content. MySQL comes with a command-line tool called [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html). You can also use tools like [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org) to export the database content. You can then import the database to your local MySQL server using either the mysql command-line, or, again, Adminer.
Once the database has been copied locally, you can put in the connection details for the local copy of the database.

You will also need to copy the content of the moodledata folder to your local server.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer :) ,  from my control panel I only have the phpmyadmin tool. Can I export with this one the database ? And how?

Comment: Open PHPMyAdmin, click 'Export', select 'SQL' as the export type.

Comment: Ok, I succeded in exporting the database. Now ... I should install on my local WAMP server a new moodle instalation ?  and after the instalation it's finished than to import somehow the exported databasae file ?

Comment: Import the exported database using phpmyadmin on your WAMP server. Then point your config.PHP file at that database. You will need to set the wwwroot to match the address of your WAMP server (and dataroot to match your copy of the server's dataroot). After that, it should just work, without any installation.